# Send the element to the next line

Tags: html, css

I want to style it in a way that the `.filter-container`s sit next to each other in a row, if a `.filter-container` has a `.header-container` it should start in a new line and the rest of the `.filter-container`s will sit next to it.

**edited: Added some bootstrap classes and vue code

Desired layout:
[image: Desired layout]

Current layout:
[image: Current layout]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        options: [
          {
            Id: 80,
            group: { GroupName: "MatrixDesc" },
            column: { ColumnAlias: "ReviewStatus" },
          },
          { Id: 81, group: { GroupName: "" }, column: { ColumnAlias: "AOI" } },
          {
            Id: 82,
            group: { GroupName: "" },
            column: {
              ColumnAlias: "Location",
            },
          },
          {
            Id: 83,
            group: { GroupName: "Header2" },
            column: { ColumnAlias: "Chemical" },
          },
          {
            Id: 84,
            group: { GroupName: "" },
            column: {
              ColumnAlias: "CollectionDate",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">  
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-end mx-3">
    <div v-for="(fdata, index) in options" :key="index">
      <span v-if="fdata.group != null">
        <div v-if="fdata.group.GroupName" class="header-container">
          <h4>{{ fdata.group.GroupName }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="Filter-with-header">
          <div class="Filter-info-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              spellcheck="false"
              v-model="fdata.column.ColumnAlias"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS you can share?  If you want help with styling you will have to share the CSS you have so far.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, showing the CSS you have tried. Also, there is a [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class that would let you select those elements which have a particular element within them...

Comment: And include enough markup to show the problem. One element doesn't do that. Edit the snippet demo above, please.